# Seeing two confirmation messages on newly created content in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am not sure why this is happening but when I create a content, I am seeing two confirmation message

[image: http://i.imgur.com/UGAUO0s.png]

I don't see anything in application.html.erb above "yield" and not able to figure out why the two confirmation messages instead of one ?

Comment: are you sure you do not have flash[:notice] twice in your view files ?
May be one is in your layout and other one is in specific view file.

Comment: @az7ar - Thanks, I got it, one is <div class="alert alert-success"> and other is <p id="notice"> I have removed id=notice in one of the view file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be the place where you are rendering your message have `two different div` having same name.

Comment: I got it, one is <div class="alert alert-success"> and other is <p id="notice"> I have removed id=notice in one of the view file